# Login to another site from nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to login into a site to scrap the data. Login works fine if try to do it through `Chrome Rest Client` but from node server I am getting `status code 302` from the website.
**Code**

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    request = require('request');



var app = express();
    app.listen(3000);

var request = request.defaults({jar:true});
app.post('/login', [express.urlencoded(), express.json()], function(req, res) {
    console.log('You are here'); console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.email));
    request.post({
      url: 'http://teeSpring.com/login/submitLogin',
      form: {
        email: "himanshu",
        password: "himanshu"
      }
    }, function(error, resposne, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error is: '+JSON.stringify(error));  
      } else if(body){
        console.log('Body is :')//+JSON.stringify(body));
      } else if(resposne) {
        console.log('Response is :'+resposne.statusCode);//+JSON.stringify(resposne));
        res.send(resposne);
      } else {
        console.log('WTF');
      }

    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting it over https instead?

Comment: Status 302 is for redirect. It should be ok. request lib should take care of it by default.

Comment: yes. Changed the url with `https` still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this - if redirected, get headers location and go there:

```
  else if(response) {
    console.log('Response is :'+response.statusCode);//+JSON.stringify(response));
    if(response.statusCode == 302 && response.headers && response.headers.location) {
      res.send(response.headers.location);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is actually returning `http://teespring.com/dashboard` which is right url after login. But I wanted to redirected to this location.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get redirected". After you get that location send another http request "http.get(response.headers.location, function(res){})" to get that url's body.

Comment: is it possible to set up a login on my node js app and land on another app hosted in different server's dashboard ?